# Array_slice in foreach loop not slicing, but I can push?

Tags: php, arrays, slice

I have an array that I want to slice records if they match conditional statements; I want to keep the original index value which is why I'm trying to slice instead of push a new array where the index value starts at 0.

```
$array = Array(
  [item1] => Array 
    (
      [sale] => 29.92
      [onhand] => 0
      [date] => 2019-09-16
    )
  [item2] => Array 
    (
      [sale] => 0
      [onhand] => 0
      [date] => 2019-09-16
    )
  [item3] => Array 
    (
      [sale] => 0
      [onhand] => 230
      [date] => 2019-09-16
    )
)
```

My conditional:

```
  foreach($items as $item){
    if( $item['sale'] == 0 && $item['onhand'] == 0) {
      array_slice($array, $item);
    }
  }
```

Desired output:

```
$array = Array(
      [item1] => Array 
        (
          [sale] => 29.92
          [onhand] => 0
          [date] => 2019-09-16
        )
      [item3] => Array 
        (
          [sale] => 0
          [onhand] => 230
          [date] => 2019-09-16
        )
    )
```

The above doesn't slice, I'm not sure if slice would be the appropriate tool here or if it is do I need additional mapping?

My other idea was to push the desired items to a new array but that writes over the index from `[item1[], item2[], item3[]]` to `[0[], 1[], 2[]]` and I very much need them to remain original.

Guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you need to store what you are removing then you need [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php):

```
// Note the $key because we need to know which position we will conditionally unset
foreach($items as $key=>$item){
    if( $item['sale'] == 0 && $item['onhand'] == 0) {
        unset($items[$key]);
    }
}
```

---

Additionally, if you wish to "slice" it some way then you actually need [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

Comment: `=` not the same as `==`